# select non group by columns with count in Mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table tbl with three columns:

```
id | fk | dateof
 1 |  1 | 2016-01-01
 2 |  1 | 2016-01-02
 3 |  2 | 2016-02-01
 4 |  2 | 2016-03-01
 5 |  3 | 2016-04-01
```

I want to get the results like this

```
Id    count of Id         max(dateof)
2    | 2                | 2016-01-02
4    | 2                | 2016-03-01
5    | 1                | 2016-04-01
```

My try

```
SELECT id,tbl.dateof dateof
FROM tbl 
INNER JOIN
 (SELECT fk, MAX(dateof) dateof ,
  count(id) cnt_of_id -- How to get this count value in the result
  FROM tbl 
  GROUP BY fk) temp
ON tbl.fk = temp.fk AND tbl.dateof = temp.dateof
```

Comment: reference it in your outer select with `temp.cnt_of_id`

Comment: Really wow i had a brain fart you are a genius i was struggling with  it for a while

Comment: Hi Hunter you should make an answer out of your comment as your comment is the answer i am looking at

Answer (score 1):

This is an aggregation query, but you don't seem to want the column being aggregated.  That is ok (although you cannot distinguish the rk that defines each row):

```
select count(*) as CountOfId, max(dateof) as maxdateof
from t
group by fk;
```

In other words, your subquery is pretty much all you need.

If you have a reasonable amount of data, you can use a MySQL trick:

```
select substring_index(group_concat(id order by dateof desc), ',', 1) as id
       count(*) as CountOfId, max(dateof) as maxdateof
from t
group by fk;
```

Note:  this is limited by the maximum intermediate size for `group_concat()`.  This parameter can be changed and it is typically large enough for this type of query on a moderately sized table.

Comment: Apologies i have corrected my question now i need the id column too

Answer (score 0):

You obviously want one result row per `fk`, so group by it. Then you want the max ID, the row count and the max date for each `fk`:

```
select 
  max(id) as max_id, 
  count(*) as cnt,
  max(date_of) as max_date_of
from tbl 
group by fk;
```